# generating digital signatures using PGP in java

Tags: java, digital-signature, pgp

I am developing a tool which generates digital signatures using DSA, RSA algorithms. I would also like to generate digital signatures and verify using PGP algorithm. I have googled and found some resources like

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/java-pretty-good-privacy-pgp.html

http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2011/08/11/pgp-encryptiondecryption-in-java/

Does anybody know good example sources for implementing PGP in java?

Answer (score 4):

Signatures are not "generated". They are made using the asymmetric private key (DSA, RSA). 
Basically you need a Java class which will let you generate the key (unless you have one already) and use that key for signing. Your options are [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) and our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-pgp.php). BouncyCastle is open-source, while SecureBlackbox comes with support, documentation and samples.